# TextMate Edit Latex Bundle Snippet, regex to replace non ascii-characters

Tags: regex, latex, textmate, oniguruma

I'm trying to modify the code from a TextMate snippet in the LaTeX Bundle. This is the code:

```
\section{${1:section name}} % (fold)
\label{sec:${2:${1/\\\\\w+\{(.*?)\}|\\\\(.)|(\w+)|([^\w\\\\]+)/(?4:_:\L$1$2$3)/g}}}
${0:$TM_SELECTED_TEXT}
% section $2 (end)
```

I want it to also change unicode accented characters into their non accented counterparts, like:

`a` into `a`

`é` into `e`

`í` into `i`

`ó` into `o`

`ú` into `u`

`ñ` into `n`

This is what it does:

```
\section{Configuración de diseño} % (fold)
\label{sec:configuración_de_diseño}

% section configuración_de_diseño (end)
```

This is what I want it to do since latex labels don't support these characters:

```
\section{Configuración de diseño} % (fold)
\label{sec:configuracion_de_diseno}

% section configuracion_de_diseno (end)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing the code of the labels to this works

```
\label{ssub:${2:${1/(\w+)(\W+$)?|\W+/${1:?${1:/asciify/downcase}:_}/g}}}
```

This is the link [Issue #87](https://github.com/textmate/latex.tmbundle/issues/87)